# Couldn't get connection factory client in error log

Tags: android

I'm starting using google maps and i added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

in my manifest file as well as apikey i got from google.

```
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView       
android:layout_width="fill_parent"

   android:layout_height="fill_parent"

   android:apiKey="api_key_here"

   android:id="@+id/mvMain"

   android:enabled="true"

   android:clickable="true"
   />
```

But on running the program, "Couldn't get connection factory client" shows up in Error log.
I will greatly appreciate any help. thank you.

Comment: can you able to post your XML too??

Answer (score 0):

This is working manifest file and take a look into this. If you are missing any thing inside your manifest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Package_name"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!--
         The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

     <!-- TODO: Replace "com.example.hellomap" with your package name -->
    <permission
        android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```